# Scala: Why is there a type mismatch in this function?

Tags: scala

I've this function whose objective is to find a Student with a required number in a List of Students.

```
type Number = Int
type Name = String
type Student = (Number, Name)
type Students = List[Student]

def searchStudentFold(t: Students, n: Number) : Option[Student] = {
  (t foldRight None) ( (x, t) => if(x._1 == n) Some(x) else t)
}
```

However this does not work due to a type mismatch when I try to return Some(x). It says that the type required is `None.type` and `Some[(Number, Name)]` was found. But it's precisely `Some[(Number, Name)]` that I want to return.

Here's the compile error message:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Some[Ficha5.Class.Student]
    (which expands to)  Some[(Int, String)]
 required: None.type
    (t foldRight None) ( (x, t) => if(x._1 == n) Some(x) else t)
```

Comment: The problem is that when you pass `None` for the initial value of `foldLeft` the compiler infers that the return type should be `None.type` which is obviously not what you want. **Scala 3** should provide better type inference, but for now use `Option.empty[Student]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the output type since fold is not contravariant to allow to upcast None to Option.

Note the `folfLeft` is better memory-wise in traversing a collection. `foldRight` goes "the wrong way" up the list. Also, what you are doing can be done with a simple `find`

```
  type Number = Int
  type Name = String
  type Student = (Number, Name)
  type Students = List[Student]

  def searchStudentFoldRight(t: Students, n: Number): Option[Student] = {
    t.foldRight[Option[Student]](None)((x, t) => if (x._1 == n) Some(x) else t)
  }
  def searchStudentFoldLeft(t: Students, n: Number): Option[Student] = {
    // Alternative way to upcast None, same result
    t.foldLeft(None:Option[Student])((t, x) => if (x._1 == n) Some(x) else t)
  }
  def searchStudentFind(t: Students, n: Number): Option[Student] = 
    t.find(_._1 == n)
```

Comment: One more way: use `none[Student]` via syntax from cats: https://typelevel.org/cats/jump_start_guide.html